# DataStax Enterprise 3.0 Visual Cluster Provisioning Failed

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Using the new DSE 3.0 Visual Cluster Provisioning tool I receive an error during node initialization - **Could not find a matching version for package dse-libpig**

`/var/lib/opscenter-agent/agent.log` contains:

```
INFO [Thread-9] 2013-02-26 15:30:41,929 Running apt-get install dry-run ERROR [Thread-9] 2013-02-26 15:30:42,966 Installation failed: 
#<RuntimeException java.lang.RuntimeException: slingshot.ExceptionInfo: throw+: {:type :installation-error, :message Could not find a matching version for package dse-libpig}>    java.lang.RuntimeException: slingshot.ExceptionInfo: throw+: {:type :installation-error, :message Could not find a matching version for package dse-libpig}
          LazySeq.java:47 clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval
          LazySeq.java:63 clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq
      ChunkedCons.java:59 clojure.lang.ChunkedCons.chunkedNext
      ChunkedCons.java:43 clojure.lang.ChunkedCons.next
              RT.java:560 clojure.lang.RT.next
              core.clj:61 clojure.core/next
            core.clj:3399 clojure.core/nthnext
        core_print.clj:55 clojure.core/print-sequential
       core_print.clj:138 clojure.core/fn
         MultiFn.java:167 clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke
            core.clj:2812 clojure.core/pr-on
            core.clj:2824 clojure.core/pr
             AFn.java:161 clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper
          RestFn.java:132 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
             core.clj:540 clojure.core/apply
            core.clj:2830 clojure.core/pr
          RestFn.java:139 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
             core.clj:540 clojure.core/apply
            core.clj:2863 clojure.core/print
          RestFn.java:137 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
             core.clj:540 clojure.core/apply
            core.clj:3716 clojure.core/print-str
          RestFn.java:436 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
             proc.clj:136 opsagent.proc/sudo
          RestFn.java:423 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
              deb.clj:157 opsagent.installation.deb/dry-run
             Var.java:369 clojure.lang.Var.invoke
             AFn.java:163 clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper
             Var.java:482 clojure.lang.Var.applyTo
             core.clj:540 clojure.core/apply
           install.clj:18 opsagent.installation.install/package-specific
          RestFn.java:439 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
           install.clj:50 opsagent.installation.install/run-installation[fn]
              AFn.java:24 clojure.lang.AFn.run
          Thread.java:662 java.lang.Thread.run Caused by: slingshot.ExceptionInfo: throw+: {:type :installation-error, :message Could not find a matching version for package dse-libpig}
              deb.clj:138 opsagent.installation.deb/make-versioned-package
            core.clj:2096 clojure.core/map[fn]
          LazySeq.java:42 clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval

 INFO [Thread-9] 2013-02-26 15:30:42,967 Request 737078db-3e68-46e9-bf95-88c9921e0451 finished with state :error : Could not find a matching version for package dse-libpig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in how OpsCenter specifies version numbers for the packages. It is using 3.0.0 when the packages are actually 3.0.

You can fix it temporarily by editing '/etc/opscenter/definitions/packages-1.json' and replacing '3.0.0' with '3.0' in the list of versions for DSE.

Answer (score 0):

OpsCenter 3.0.1 is now available, and fixes this.